# Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have a map fragment class and I added a button on top of it. When I click on it I am calling another fragment class with a simple textview and save button. When save is clicked I want to go back to my mapfragment class. Right now it is throwing an error when I click save and go back. The error is when it is inflating the class > Just wondering if I am doing anything wrong while popping from the backstack. I just want to remove the last one and go back to my map. 
My map layout is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">


    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

MapFragment is as follows:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maplayout,container,false);
  return v;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    fragment = (MapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

The back method:

```
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack("TEXT_FRAGMENT", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

                    fm.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.map_tab,
                                    mapFragment,
                                    "maptab")
                            .addToBackStack("maptab")
                            .commit();
```

The error is: Fragment does not have a view.

The map_tab is the tab on which MapFragment was added. The map fragment is added on top of this.

**EDIT:** In the back method I added  fm.popBackStack("TEXT_FRAGMENT", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE

but then this gives me the error when I go back to my Map Fragment and on inflating I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work finally. Had to remove the mapfragment before adding a new fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Don't commit a new Fragment. Instead, 
Look at the `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` methods (there are several to choose from)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()

Comment: I added the pop method(Added in EDIT) and it inflates back but gives me the error as well. It goes in OnCreate and I have a try catch on View and catches the exeption here.